# Ransack sort on count of HABTM or HMT associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, ransack

I have a HABTM relationship between the `Theme` and `Quote` models. The `themes` `index` view displays the count of quotes associated with each theme. I'd like to add a Ransack `sort_link` on that column, so the `themes` can be sorted by their count of associated `quotes`.

I have done this successfully with `has_many` associations using a counter cache column, but Rails does not support counter cache columns for HABTM associations.

So far, I've got a scope that adds a virtual attribute called `quotes_count` (by performing a single query, avoiding  N+1) to the `Theme` model:

```
scope :with_quotes_count, -> do
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN quotes_themes on quotes_themes.theme_id = themes.id')
    .select('themes.*, COUNT(quotes_themes.quote_id) as quotes_count')
    .group('themes.id')
end
```

Seems like I have to convert the above scope into a "Ransacker" using ARel but so far all my attempts have failed.

I'm using Rails 4.2.2, ARel 6.0.4 and PostgreSQL 9.5.4.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can ranksack sort with scopes. I've always done it with Arel wrappers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have your entities queried with the above scope, for example your index query always has:

```
# controller
@search = Theme.ransack(params[:q])
@themes = @search.result(distinct: true).with_quotes_count
```

Have a try of:

```
# model
ransacker :quotes_count_sort do
    Arel.sql('quotes_count')
end
```

And use the name of the sort in `sort_link`?

Comment: Awesome, do you mind accepting it as the answer please? :)

Comment: Sure! In case you are interested, I also have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029562/activerecord-error-when-trying-to-order-results-from-a-scope/42031400?noredirect=1#comment71317696_42031400) question you may know the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

there is some patch that could be helpful for you to use scope 
Visit https://gist.github.com/ledermann/4135215

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That patch was written 4 years ago. Ransack [currently supports scopes](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#using-scopesclass-methods). The thing is, so far I have been unable to write a scope that works as described in this question.