# ActiveRecord: error when trying to order results from a scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  scope :with_users_count, -> do
    joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN masters_users on masters_users.master_id = masters.id')
      .select('masters.*, COUNT(masters_users.user_id) as users_count')
      .group('masters.id')
  end
end
```

I'm trying to do:

```
Master.with_users_count.includes(:language).order('languages.name')
```

And the following error happens:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "languages.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Could you please advise on how to change **the scope** so this error is fixed?

**Edit (additional info):**

- The above code is meant to add the `quotes_count` "attribute" to the results, so I can display the count of users for each master without N+1 and without the need for a counter cache (which seems to be buggy for HABTM).
- The scope works just fine, the error appears when I call the `order` method.
- The sorting is done by the Ransack gem, so I have no control over how it's done. I have used the `order` method as a way to reproduce the error that happens when trying to sort via Ransack `sort_link`, in an attempt to avoid adding more complexity to the question.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're just trying to get a count of the number of users for each master alongside the columnular data, is that correct?

Comment: coreyward: That's correct. Trying to get the count of users for each master so I can use it the index view without generating N+1 queries. I have edited the question to provide additional info.

Comment: Okay, I think you can/should do away with your `order` altogether; since you're attempting to load `languages` as a relationship. If you want to sort `masters` by the associated `languages.name`, you need to use another join. You would be well served by converting this to use Arel, where the AST can better manage the relationships and table names you've already defined with your models.

Comment: @coreyward: Thanks for the great advice. However, I am unable to use another join. The sorting is done by the Ransack gem, so I have no control over how it's done. I have used the `order` method as a way to reproduce the error that happens when trying to sort via Ransack `sort_link`, in an attempt to avoid adding more complexity to the question. I should have explained this in the original question, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately that's how you have to do it in SQL. There's no way to sort based off of another table without defining the relationship between the tables for the database to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can have left_outer_join with languages also in the scope, it should remove the error while ordering because it will have language table joined in the sql query.

```
scope :with_users_count, -> do
joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN masters_users on masters_users.master_id = masters.id LEFT OUTER JOIN languages on languages.id = masters.language_id')
  .select('masters.*, COUNT(masters_users.user_id) as users_count')
  .group('masters.id')
```

end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide some sample code so I can select this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Than you. Unfortunately, I have tried your code and got a the following error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "languages.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: What happens if you try adding `languages.*` in your `select()`?